# How to make Noise modifier on f-curve loop?

Tags: graph-editor, fcurves

I am trying to make a looping animation. I am animating the camera movement using the noise modifier of an f-curve. I would like my start keyframe and end+1 keyframe to be the same so that the animation loops.

I can accomplish this by setting the Restrict Frame Range setting to the start and end+1 frames. However, this just makes the value linearly jump back to the value for those frames which does not result in a smooth animation.

I would like the slopes of the fcurve before these two points to be match up so that the animation is smooth.

Comment: You could try setting *Restrict Frame Range* > *End* to end - 1, to ensure starting and ending frames are the same. For more finetuning it's also possible to set *In* and *Out* values to something like 5 or 10 frames, like [here](http://i.imgur.com/Mg9KEN3.webm).